# MySQL Multi-Delete. Is it possible to multi-delete referenced rows?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, cascading-deletes, sql-delete

If I have a parent table and a child table, is it possible to multi-delete the rows in them without having a "ON DELETE CASCADE" constraint?

In this example:

```
create table a(id int primary key);
create table b(id int primary key, a_id int,
 constraint fkb foreign key (a_id) references a(id));
```

Is it not possible to do something like this in order to delete rows in tables a and b? :-(

```
delete a, b
from b
inner join a on a.id = b.a_id
where a.id = ?;

Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`erasmusu6`.`b`, CONSTRAINT `fkb` FOREIGN KEY (`a_id`) REFERENCES `a` (`id`))
```

I would like to multidelete rows but **not to set a "ON `DELETE` CASCADE" constraint**. Also I need to filter the `DELETE` command with a `WHERE` clause. Is this possible or should I have to make as many `DELETE`s as tables in the multidelete?

Comment: SET foreign_key_checks = 0; and after you delete SET foreign_key_checks = 1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem with optimizer hints, by specifying the exact join order in the DELETE command:

```
delete a, b
from b
STRAIGHT_JOIN a on a.id = b.a_id
where a.id = ?;
```

MySQL will DELETE b rows first thanks to the optimizer hint STRAIGHT_JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

This is the note from mysql documentation page (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html):

***"If you use a multiple-table DELETE statement involving InnoDB tables for which there are foreign key constraints, the MySQL optimizer might process tables in an order that differs from that of their parent/child relationship. In this case, the statement fails and rolls back. Instead, you should delete from a single table and rely on the ON DELETE capabilities that InnoDB provides to cause the other tables to be modified accordingly."***

So, this implies that you are forced not to use multi delete option!

Hope that helps..

Comment: You can tell the optimizer how to make its work with hints like STRIGHT_JOIN! :-)